# Why won't my viewport tag properly use device width on most mobile devices?

Tags: html, mobile, viewport, meta-tags, device-width

I am using following meta tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" data-placeholder-focus="false">
    <head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0" /> 
    <meta name="mobileoptimized" content="0" />
    <title>index</title>
    <meta name="description" content="" /> 
    <meta name="keywords" content="" /> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">  

    </head>
```

when I open website from mobile, it is not responsive at all. I have not changed my css code.

Please, help me! Thank you!

Comment: `initial-scale=0`? It should be 1

Comment: @Super Cool Handsome Gel Boy I have changed from 0 to 1. but not working.

Comment: Delete the mobile optimized meta tag

Comment: @Super Cool Handsome Gel Boy   its not solution of problem.

Comment: Sorry can't help unless you explain the term "unresponsive""

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Also, do you mean responsive as in scaling across form factor or responsive as in not frozen?